# JTree node Rename

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am using a JTree and in this to **raname a JTree node** I am using right click(Rename through popup) or F2 key or double click. But problem is : when I rename a name and hit **Enter** key, node successfully renamed and when I rename a name and click anywhere on the frame(**windows explorer style**), node name does not rename.

Please give me a solution for this problem and Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your current approach? Can you show us some code? Are you implementing a `TreeModelListener`?

Comment: yes I am using TreeModelListener......

Comment: This is the method that I call at the time of pressing F2 key after selection of node.....

Comment: treeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) jTree.getModel();

Comment: treeModel.addTreeModelListener(this);

Comment: TreePath currentSelection = jTree.getSelectionPath();

Comment: currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (currentSelection
                                                               .getLastPathComponent());

Comment: jTree.setEditable(true);
     jTree.startEditingAtPath(currentSelection);

Comment: and this function is used at the time of pressing Enter key.....

Comment: ...............                             currentNode.setUserObject();

Answer (score 6):

It's probably a little late, but the correct solution is to call `JTree.setInvokesStopCellEditing(true)`. This will cause the tree to execute the rename when the user hits enter, or when the cell editor loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to save the current edit by clicking elsewhere in the tree is not something that comes standard as part of the default `JTree` implementation. You're going to have to get into the details of how to use trees and do some special customization in order to achieve this functionality. This sounds like it would involve something with the focus of Swing components, i.e., when the tree gains focus, if the node is being edited, then save the node rename.

Comment: Could you please tell me which method is called at the time of pressing Enter key after editing a tree node.......

Comment: Could you please tell me which method is called at the time of pressing Enter key after editing a tree node.......otherwise could you explain your suggestion in detail

Comment: You can add a `FocusListener` on your tree cell editor. The Enter key is bound by the cell editor.